# How expensive is os.Getenv?

Tags: go, environment-variables

I have a piece of code that's called every few seconds and makes use of an environment variable:

```golang
for {
    myVar := os.Getenv("MY_VAR")
    //Do something
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}
```

But how costly are repeat calls to `os.Getenv`?

The value of the environment variable will not change during runtime, so I could set it as a package level variable:

```golang
package blah

var myVar = os.Getenv("MY_VAR")
```

But this does hurt testability of the code.

Should I set it as a package level variable? Or is `os.Getenv` benign enough?

**EDIT:**
I've benchmarked the call to `os.Getenv` but is it reliable?

```golang
package main_test

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

var result string

func BenchmarkEnv(b *testing.B) {
    var r string
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        r = os.Getenv("PATH")
    }
    result = r
}
```

```sh
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkEnv-8      20000000            78.7 ns/op
PASS
```

Comment: You can benchmark this and find out. My prediction: it's fast enough to not care.

Comment: Why do you repeatedly read it if it doesn't change?

Comment: read it before the loop?

Comment: `But to my understanding we should avoid package level variables.`: Why? If you need a package level variable, then use one. From your example, you also obviously have the choice to scope it outside the loop, so why look it up every time?

Comment: @JimB Concurrency is not an issue here, but it does limit testing ability

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen It's possible and and is easy in the simplified example I've given, but it will add complexity to the actual code I'm working on so I'm looking for ways around it

Comment: uncomfortable with this question being marked down; guiding curious developers towards golang benchmark capabilities is a good thing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can benchmark os.Getenv and see how fast it is.

By looking at its implementation [here](https://golang.org/src/syscall/env_unix.go?s=1612:1662#L61), it costs:

1. A read-lock;
2. Lookup in global map;
3. Linear search of char '='.